# Sockets in WebView Android

Tags: android, sockets, webview

Im having an application written in .NET (i guess) and is quite responsive. The idea is to wrap the app as an android app. The android app is going to have many more functionalities and this webview is just one of them.

My question is the current web app is using some sockets to push data to the page. So the content changes without refreshing the page. Will that functionality be intact in android webview too?

I should have tried this by building the app, but my bad they currently do not have any data and aren't pushing either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. From what I can tell, Android browser (aka WebView) does not support WebSockets : http://mobilehtml5.org/

Although there is a workaround using Socket.IO which you can try out: http://chpeck.tumblr.com/post/37273036645/socket-io-with-android-webview

Gist: https://gist.github.com/secobarbital/4220309

Another easier alternative is to use [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) on your website, which will automatically fall-back to Flash if it detects a browser that does not support WebSockets.

**EDIT**

In Android 4.4+ original WebKit-based WebView has been replaced by Chromium which supports WebSockets among other goodies. More info: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/android-4-4-kitkat-browser-chrome-webview